# %>% operator R yields unexpected error

Tags: r

```
library(magrittr) 

myDf <- dataSetSubsetting 
        %>% !is.na(.[,c("colx")]) 
        %>% !is.na(.[,c("coly")])
        %>% someFunction(.[,c("colx", "coly")], .)
```

That how I thought the `magrittr` works. However, it raises me an error:

```
384: myDf <- dataSetSubsetting %>% !is.na(.[,c("colx")])
385: %>%
     ^
```

Why?!

Comment: Could you provide information about 'dataSetSubsetting', what you try to achieve and what your expected outcome is!?

Comment: @Cleb Its a dataset I subset (dataframe). I then need to subset it again and apply some function. There is not more to it.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Have you checked in `sessionInfo()` to not accidentally load `dplyr` and mask the `%>%` in this way...

Comment: try switching the operators: `dataSetSubsetting %>%
                                              !is.na(.[,c("colx")]) %>%
                                              !is.na(.[,c("coly")]) %>%...` formatting doesn't work in comments, but object first, then %>% in the same line, repeat as necessary

Comment: @erasmortg That worked, sort of. But why?! In other parts of the programm is start a new line with every `%>%` and it works. When I write all of that into one line its not readable...

Comment: What do you mean 'sort of'? It didn't give the expected result? As for formatting, you can write object first, then %>% and in another line continue (object first then %>%...)My guess is  that, in other parts of your script, you actually have some parentheses that group the operations. I don't recall having seen your format working before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more detailed explanation based on erasmortg's comment.

```
library(dplyr)

#* Works
mtcars %>%
  mutate(am = factor(am, 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual")))

#* Fails: the interpreter looks at the end of the first 
#*        line and sees no operator, so it prints 'mtcars'
#*        and declares the operation complete.
#*        It then looks at the second line and can't find
#*        the left hand side for '%>%', causing an error.
mtcars
  %>% mutate(am = factor(am, 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual")))

#* Fails: Similar story to the previous example.  In this case,
#*        printing is delayed until all of the statements within
#*        the braces successfully run.
{mtcars
  %>% mutate(am = factor(am, 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual")))}

#* Succeeds: The interpreter sees that you've opened
#*    with parentheses, and tries to connect all of the
#*    lines into a coherent statement.  With the parentheses,
#*    when the interpreter sees no operator at the end of 
#*    'mtcars', it says to itself, "I hope I find one on the 
#*    next line" and tries to piece it together.
(mtcars
  %>% mutate(am = factor(am, 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual"))))
```